# "Гонконжский" через Ж

Tags: грамотная-речь, чередования

Скажите, допустим ли этот вариант?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такие альтернативные прилагательные имеют *ограниченное* употребление, обозначая не принадлежность топониму, а нечто свойственное отдельным его аспектам, например не Петербургу, а петербуржцам (нет слов "петербургец", "таганрогец", "оренбургец" - такие слова оканчиваются на "-жец") - *петербуржские* манеры, традиции, но "*петербургские* сезоны". Можно было бы ожидать подобного и в случае с Гонконгом (название тоже оканчивается на согласную "г"), однако, при всей условной корректности, это непривычно и может восприниматься как фамильярность, поскольку большинство носителей русского языка мало знакомо напр. с бытом *жителей Гонконга*. Даже слово "*гонконжец*", которое охотно употребляется в сети осведомлёнными китаистами и путешественниками, словари не жалуют. В словаре синонимов и википедиях можно найти лишь "*гонконгец*" и даже "*сянганец*" (от произношения *того же* кантонского названия на основном, официальном китайском диалекте - в своё время тележурналисты распространили заблуждение, что "Гонконг *переименован* в провинцию Сянган" - на самом деле название не менялось). Так что формально "*гонконжец*" и (тем более - как производное слово) "*гонконжский*" в норму не входят, оставаясь чем-то вроде элитарных жаргонизмов.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр!